# How do I prevent a Phoenix Live View from removing DOM elements put there by JavaScript?

Tags: phoenix-live-view

I haven't yet found a way to consistently prevent Phoenix Live Views from removing elements from the DOM that were put there by JavaScript. Here is a snippet from a [crude chat app](https://github.com/ijt/rantclub/tree/39a3d71ce744fea6ac71d64afdacea9da6060b53) that uses JavaScript to add a smiley face after the page loads:

```html
<span><%= live_patch "New Chat", to: Routes.chat_index_path(@socket, :new) %></span>

<div id="smiley" style="font-size: 80px" phx-update="ignore"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#smiley').html('')
  });
</script>
```

[image: initial page with smiley face added by JavaScript]

The `phx-update="ignore"` attribute prevents the smiley face from disappearing right away, but adding a new chat causes it to disappear:

[image: page after adding chat, with smiley face removed by Live View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent it from disappearing after New Chat by using `phx-hook` like this:

```html
<div id="smiley" style="font-size: 80px" phx-hook="Smiley"></div>
```

and in app.js:

```js
let Hooks = {}
Hooks.Smiley = {
    mounted() {
        this.el.innerHTML = ''
    }
}

let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken}, hooks: Hooks})
```

The complete code is here: https://github.com/ijt/rantclub/tree/c383530ce9749beb21f2c60605576f0d047043f8.

One caveat: for some reason this does not prevent Delete from removing the smiley face.